How to calculate a daily return and cumulative daily compounding return in PowerBI?
I have a table RAW_DATA with columns such as Date, Sector, Region, Stock ID, GainLoss and Basis.
I've created a measure that calculates the daily return
ROIC_DTD = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM(SummaryTable[PnL]),SUM(SummaryTable[Basis])))

Next  I'm trying to calculate a daily compounding return which in excel is product(1+ Daily Returns)
How can I accomplish this in Power BI such that it will still operate as a daily compounding calculation even if dates are not in the rows of my matrix?
For example, if I want to see the 1/1/24 - 3/15/24 (Set in a slider) Return by Sector (daily compounded), how can I do that?
I've tried this with no luck:
CALCULATE(PRODUCTX(SummaryTable,1+SummaryTable[ROIC_DTD]-1),ALLSELECTED(SummaryTable))

CALCULATE(PRODUCTX(SummaryTable,1+SummaryTable[ROIC_DTD]-1),ALLSELECTED(SummaryTable))


Please add some sample data with your expected output.

You'll need a measure to compute the compounded return over a date range. Here's a possible solution using DAX:
    DAX
Code kopiëren
Compounded_Return = 
VAR SelectedDates = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES('Calendar'[Date]),
        DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date], MIN('Calendar'[Date]), MAX('Calendar'[Date]))
    )
VAR DailyReturns = 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SelectedDates,
        "DailyReturn", [ROIC_DTD]
    )
VAR CompoundedReturn = 
    PRODUCTX (
        DailyReturns,
        1 + [DailyReturn]
    ) - 1
RETURN
    CompoundedReturn

